# I am trying to figure out how to remove the top margins when viewing on smaller screens(mobile, tablet)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and have a layout. I have a row with 4 columns and I the content withing each div has a different top margins. This gives a cascading effect and looks good on desktop. The problem is that when viewed on smaller screens, the margin remains and leaves a big gab in between the content. I would like the divs to stack with a small (10px) space between them. I have tried playing with the css and tried adding @media, but still get the big space.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container" style='min-height:600px'><br>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-1'>
            <div class='col-1-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-2'>
            <div class='col-2-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-3'>
            <div class='col-3-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-4'>
            <div class='col-4-box'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the UPDATED CSS:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-1-box, .col-2-box, .col-3-box, .col-4-box {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }
}
#col-1{
    background-color:;

}
#col-2{
    background-color:;

}
#col-3{
    background-color:;

}
#col-4{
    background-color:;

}
.col-1-box{
    margin-top:0%;
    padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px -2px #6E6E6E;
}
.col-2-box{
    margin-top:25%;
    padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px -2px #6E6E6E;
}
.col-3-box{
    margin-top:50%;
    padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px -2px #6E6E6E;
}
.col-4-box{
    margin-top:75%;
    padding:0px 10px0 10px;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px -2px #6E6E6E;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where is your `@media`??

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a media query to your CSS that will change the padding on mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-2-box, .col-3-box, .col-3-box, .col-4-box {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

You’ve also got a typo in your `.col-4-box` styles. Change the padding to `padding:0px 10px 0 10px;`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried that but the space between each div increases on mobile. I have updated the code above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The big gab between the content, it causes by `min-height`, so try to set it to zero, and the `margin-top` to 10px. Try this

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  #col-1, #col-2, #col-3, #col-4{
    min-height:0px;
  }
  .col-2-box, .col-3-box, .col-4-box{
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```css
    #col-1{
        background-color:;
        min-height:500px;
    }
    #col-2{
        background-color:;
        min-height:500px;
    }
    #col-3{
        background-color:;
        min-height:500px;
    }
    #col-4{
        background-color:;
        min-height:500px;
    }
    .col-1-box{
        margin-top:0%;
        padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
        min-height:200px;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #6E6E6E;
    }
    .col-2-box{
        margin-top:25%;
        padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
        min-height:200px;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #6E6E6E;
    }
    .col-3-box{
        margin-top:50%;
        padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
        min-height:200px;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #6E6E6E;
    }
    .col-4-box{
        margin-top:75%;
        padding:0px 10px0 10px;
        min-height:200px;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px -4px #6E6E6E;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
      #col-1, #col-2, #col-3, #col-4{
        min-height:0px;
      }
      .col-2-box, .col-3-box, .col-4-box{
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style='min-height:600px'>
    <br>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-1'>
            <div class='col-1-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-2'>
            <div class='col-2-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-3'>
            <div class='col-3-box'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3' id='col-4'>
            <div class='col-4-box'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Amine. I tried your tip and still getting same result. The effect I am trying to achieve can be seen on hostgator.com. The second section has the cascading boxes that I desire and when you minimize the screen, they stack nicely. Mine don't. :(